# How to pass Id value from javascript back to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a value from onchange function back to the controller

View

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Please select supplier</label>
        <select asp-for="@Model.Transaction.supplier_id" asp-items="@ViewBag.Sup" value="@ViewBag.Sup" class="form-control" id="Select" onchange="myFunction()">
              <option selected disabled>--Supplier--</option>
            </select>
<br>
<canvas id="myChartD" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;border: 2px solid black"></canvas>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
var xValues = [1,2,3];
var yValues = [@ViewBag.Onescore,@ViewBag.Twoscore,@ViewBag.Threescore];

new Chart("myChartD", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Select").value;
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Sheet()
        {
            var sup = _db.Supplier.ToList();
            ViewBag.Sup = new SelectList(sup, "supplier_id", "supplier_name");
            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Sheet(EvaluateSheet obj)
{
            var x = "";
            var jan = _db.Transaction.FirstOrDefault(t => t.supplier_id == x && t.transaction_monthly.Month == 1);
            var feb = _db.Transaction.FirstOrDefault(t => t.supplier_id == x && t.transaction_monthly.Month == 2);
            var mar = _db.Transaction.FirstOrDefault(t => t.supplier_id == x && t.transaction_monthly.Month == 3);
   
             ViewBag.Onescore = jan.topic1score + jan.topic2score;
             ViewBag.Twoscore = feb.topic1score + feb.topic2score;
             ViewBag.Threescore = mar.topic1score + mar.topic2score;
             _db.Transaction.Add(Model);
             _db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is it possible to pass x value back to the controller in order to display the chart by getting `supplier_id` from the x value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Ajax call to send the x value, then set the values for the graph via a `JSON` return.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Select").value;

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/{ControllerName}/{MethodName}",
    data: { x: x },
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
            //retured values for the graphs
    }
});
}
```